# Error: libopencv_dnn.so.3.4: cannot open shared object file when using node-opencv

Tags: node.js, opencv

I'm using the [opencv](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) library for Node, and am running into some weird path issue on Linux

When simply issuing `require('opencv');`, I get the following error:

```
Error: libopencv_dnn.so.3.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

I looked at [binding.gyp](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/blob/master/binding.gyp) and if I execute the [find-opencv.js](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/blob/master/utils/find-opencv.js) utility I get what *seems* to be a sane answer:

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/opencv# node utils/find-opencv.js --libs
-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core
```

I can see *opencv_dnn* in there, and if I `ls` the libs directory:

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep dnn
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 Mar 20 17:23 libopencv_dnn.so -> libopencv_dnn.so.3.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        22 Mar 20 17:23 libopencv_dnn.so.3.4 -> libopencv_dnn.so.3.4.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12970608 Mar 20 17:20 libopencv_dnn.so.3.4.5
```

I see that **`libopencv_dnn.so.3.4`** definitely exists.

Not really sure what my next step is here...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so running `ldconfig` seemed to "fix" the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have two option actually:

1- Use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to OpenCV build libs

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/src/app/build/lib
```

2- Easy way is to use `ldconfig`